# How to loop through list of classes and assign them to a variable

Tags: dart

How to loop through a list of classes and assign them to a variable based on a condition.
example:

```
class A {
  static List items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
}

class B {
  static List items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
}

class C {
  static List items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
}


class SelectSuitableClass {
  var selectedClass;
  String item;
  List myClasses = [A, B, C];

  SelectSuitableClass(this.item) {

    outerFor: for (var cl in myClasses){

       for (var i in cl.items) {
         if (item.contains(i)) {

           selectedClass = cl();
           break outerFor;

         }
       }

       if(selectedClass == null) {
         throw 'some error';
       }
    }   
  }
}
```

in python this code is possible.

How can we achieve this in dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this in Dart without using reflection (`dart:mirrors`) which is not available on most platforms.

The list of classes contains `Type` objects, `[A, B, C]`, and a `Type` object is only good for two things: Comparing with equality and using as a token when using the mirrors library.

You cannot access a static member of a class through the `Type` object representing that class, you have to access the static member in a way where the compiler can *statically* see which member you are accessing.

In order to do a lookup where the result depends on the receiver, you need to have an instance member.